# C3.js Multiple Y in a multiple line chart (no static column name)

Tags: javascript, c3.js

Normally in C3.js to create multiple Y axes you would doe something like this:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
    ],
    axes: {
        data1: 'y',
        data2: 'y2'
    }
},
axis: {
    y2: {
        show: true
    }
}
});
```

However my data is different/dynamic something like this:

```
['week', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
['feed cow 30', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
['weight cow 30', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
['week', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
['feed cow 40', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
['weight cow 40', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
['week', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
['feed cow 60', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
['weight cow 60', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
```

So my Column names are dynamic. I create an array for the plotting of the data X axes. So my data is like this:

```
 data: {       
                xs: xs,
                columns: graphdata,                
                type: "line", .......
```

Now I want to have 2 Y axes, one for weight and one for feed. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
var axisData = {}; axisData[graphdata[2][0]] = "y"; axisData[graphdata[1][0]] = "y2";

....

data: {       
                xs: xs,
                columns: graphdata,                
                axes : axisData,
                type: "line",         

            },
```